# Android - Cuando aplico un theme a un activity con un menú desaparece el ActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbar

Tengo un activity con un menú y quiero aplicarle un tema claro para desactivar el modo oscuro del teléfono en la app.

Cuando a esta activity le aplico cualquier tema, el actionBar con el menú desaparece, en cambio si no le aplico ningún tema sale todo perfecto, pero se aplica el modo oscuro. Quisiera poder aplicarle el tema claro como al resto de activities para desactivar el modo oscuro en toda la aplicación

**Activity sin tema aplicado**

[image: Activity sin aplicar el tema claro]

**Manifest**

```
<activity 
   android:name=".ReproductorVideosActivity"
   android:label="@string/reproductor"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Cuando le aplico el tema claro:

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.AleTube" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red2</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/redOscuro</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
    </style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redOscuro</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    </style>
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".ReproductorVideosActivity"
                  android:label="@string/reproductor"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.AleTube">
        </activity>
```

**Tema aplicado y la actionBar desaparece**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y en cambio en otra activity con el mismo tema aplicado sale todo perfecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El activity que da problemas tiene un reproductor de YouTube y extiende de YouTubeBaseActivity, no se si eso tendrá algo que ver

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el tema `DarkActionBar` del cual hereda `AleTube`:

```
<style name="Theme.AleTube" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Este no debe tener especificado

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Comment: Sí ese es el tema que tengo puesto en los activities que quiero que salga la actionBar y no tiene lo de `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` Lo tengo todo tal y como he compartido